# Does the address on a W9 matter? IE for state taxes?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, california, state-income-tax, new-york

I have a PO box in CA where I have been receiving mail, and wish to continue to as I don't have a stable address in NYC where I live.

When I send clients a W9, would it be an issue to use a CA address? Does the address on the W9 matter for state income taxes?

I am an independent contractor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have tax forms mailed doesn't make a difference regarding your taxes.

Many people move during the year, so they have their tax forms sent where they live at the end of the year not where they were when they did the work.

The states where you live and where you do the work will both try and tax your income, unless there is a reciprocity agreement that specifies which is the primary.